# expo-payments-stripe doesn't work on real android device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I try to use https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/payments/ in my project. It is stated that "Stripe is supported in the managed workflow for Android" however it crashes for me on a real device. It works perfectly on the emulator and on the device with Expo Go but it doesn't work as a standalone installed apk created by "expo build:android -t apk". I have uploaded my reproducer here https://bitbucket.org/zahoranszky/stripe/src/master/ If you run it crashes all the time. It is the setOptionsAsync method. I found many complaints about it on the net but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Stripe will work on Expo go out of the box, but to build standalone app ios/android you must use EAS build to compile native code.

CHeck https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/#standalone-apps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).